# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, linker command failed

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, linker-errors

I just started learning c++ and makefiles. Now I'm stuck.
There seem to be dozens of questions like this, but I can't figure out which answer applies to my situation.  This answer is probably obvious. Some clues for where to look and reasons for what I am doing is wrong would be greatly appreciated!

This is my error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "App::init(char const*, int, int, int, int, bool)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [../out/MYAPP] Error 1
```

This is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "App.h"

// our App object
App* a_app = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    a_app = new App();

    a_app->init("Hello World", 100, 100, 640, 480, true);

    //...etc more code
    return 0;
}
```

**App.h**

```
#ifndef __App__
#define __App__

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class App
{
public:

    App(){}
    ~App(){}

    bool init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);
    //..etc
private:

};

#endif /* defined(__App__) */
```

**App.cpp**

```
#include "App.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool App::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen)
{   
    // attempt to initialize SDL
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        cout << "SDL init success \n";

        int flags = 0;
        if(fullscreen)
        {
            flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
        }

        // init the window
        m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
            //...etc 

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "SDL init fail \n";
        return false; // SDL init fail
    }

    cout << "SDL init success \n";
    m_bRunning = true; // everything inited successfully, start the main loop

    return true;
}
```

And finally my **makefile**

```
CXX = clang++
SDL = -framework SDL2 -framework SDL2_image
INCLUDES = -I ~/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -I ~/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Headers
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -c -std=c++11 $(INCLUDES)
LDFLAGS = $(SDL) -F ~/Library/Frameworks/
SRC = src
BUILD = build
OUT = ../out
EXE = $(OUT)/MYAPP

OBJECTS = $(BUILD)/main.o $(BUILD)/App.o

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS) | $(OUT)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.cpp | $(BUILD)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

$(BUILD):
    mkdir -p $(BUILD)

$(OUT):
    mkdir -p $(OUT)

clean:
    rm $(BUILD)/*.o && rm $(EXE)
```

Comment: `$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@` should be `$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@` -- the `$<` pseudo-variable only expands to the first dependency, which is `main.o`. That matches with the linker error.

Comment: @H2CO3: Post it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not linking all the object files.

```
$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

should be

```
$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

since the `$<` pseudo-variable expands to **only the first dependency,** which is `main.o`. That matches with the linker error.

In fact, **making this modification alone makes the error go away on my machine.**

Comment: Also, as a side note, if you weren't linking this with `clang` and the OS X LLVM-based toolchain, there's a good chance that you would need to swap the linker flags and the object files, as in `$(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@`.

Comment: wow, ok! Thanks that helps a lot.
No more errors now, all is working.

Do you know of any good makefile references for a beginner? I know there are the official docs, but they are sort of overwhelming.

Comment: @bottleboot Well, I don't know one specific make-it-all tutorial; I remember that getting a good grasp on Makefiles took me quite a while, basically I was just googling around when I needed to learn about a particular feature.